# jQuery - scroll to content smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a simple thing. I have a web page with a big full-width header. I need it to be scrolled all the way down to the content on the first mouse wheel scroll.

I have something like this:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($('.site-content').first().offset().top)
        },2000);
    });
```

It works almost fine, but - at first it makes the short scroll down (the original scroll) and after that scroll animation begins. So it doesn't look smoothly at all.

What is the best way how to make this happen smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

this isn't tested; I'm not at a computer right now

but try changing

```
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($('.site-content').first().offset().top)
    },500);
});
```

but keep in mind that this will disable the users scroll and your function will have full controll

Comment: well, it seemed like it really could work, but it doesn't. Mouse scroll is still enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Only on first scroll?

```js
var scrolled = false;
$(window).scroll(function(e) {
  if (scrolled == false) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($('.site-content').first().offset().top)
    }, 2000);
    scrolled = true;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: #000; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
}

.site-content {
  background-color: #F00;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="site-content"></div>
</body>
```